# Delete specific lines in multiple Text Files with freeware App?

Tags: replace

Does anyone know how to delete specific lines in multiple Text Files with a freeware App?
For instance the first 2 Lines or the last 2 lines or line 4 and 6 or etc. 
Replace Pioneer can do this and Soobolsoft but they are paid Apps.
I'm an average computer user and not a programmer so I don't know how to work with scripts. I don't have to do this often therefore I'm looking for a freeware............

Comment: I think you'll find SO is full of people who would consider a script an obvious solution to do what you ask. You know, "Professional and Enthusiast Programmers ..." *and you haven't specified which OS you're using*

Comment: I don't even know how to think about this problem except in terms of scripts any more ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention my OS. It's Microsoft Windows XP Sp3 Home Edition......

Answer (score 0):

I've found a freeware that can do this.
It's name is Text Converter Basic and can be found [here](http://www.sttmedia.com/textconverter)