# Delete text from multiple files

Tags: macos, text, file-io, osx-snow-leopard

I want to delete text from multiple files. It could be from 10 to 1000 files, so deleting it by hand is too much work. 
I found a couple of SO questions, such as:
[Delete specific lines in multiple Text Files with freeware App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405642/delete-specific-lines-in-multiple-text-files-with-freeware-app) but none of them helped

To do find and replace, I could write a perl command, but it lacks options.
For example, I want to delete the first four lines in all files.
Does anyone know a solution? Or maybe an app? I would prefer something without VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sed(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) or [`awk(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html) would be great for this job.  For example, to delete the first 4 lines of all of the `.txt` files in the current directory:

```
sed -i~ 1,4d *.txt
```

This will delete the first 4 lines of all `.txt` files anywhere in a subdirectory of the current directory:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.txt -exec sed -i~ 1,4d '{}' +
```

Answer (score 2):

BBEdit TextWrangler (free) has the capability to make changes in multiple files. The command is "Multi-File Search" under the "Search"menu.

Comment: Thanks but can't find that textwrangler could delete couple of lines, it can replace, but the file searching doesn't give me a good result. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

SED would probably work very well.  Is free and can do a lot of what you want.  There are windows, mac and linux ports.

[SED Stream Editor](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Answer (score 1):

If for example you are trying to remove comments from multiple files of code, and there is a pattern like all comments start with #, then open up a console, move into the directory where your files reside, and type the following commands:

```
foreach file (*dat)
sed '/^\#/d' $file > tt
mv tt $file
end
```

In other cases, you may have a text file for which a give number of lines on top are comments. Let's say that you want to get rid of the first 3 lines. Well, here is the trick:

```
sed '1,3d' myFile > tt 
mv tt myFile
```

Here is what happens:

- `sed '/^\#/d' myFile` removes all lines starting with # from the file myFile and outputs the result in the console.
- `> tt` redirects the output into a temporary file called tt
- `mv tt myFile` moves the temporary file tt to myFile